Why does Mathematica says it didn't create a context when Needs was evaluated but it does?
In Mathematica 14.0.0 (MacOS Sonoma 14.4.1) I made a simple package consisting of two "sub packages". One of them is loaded as "private" from with the main package:
The package structure is in the subdirectory LP in my user directory (MacOS /Users/twan:
LP/
   Kernel/
       init.wl
   Main.wl
   Sub.wl

The contents of the files is as follows:
For init.wl:
(* ::Package:: *)

Get["LP`Main`"]

For Main.wl:
(* ::Package:: *)

BeginPackage["LP`Main`"]

dummy::usage = "dummy[s] with s a string to be formatted by the format function in LP`Sub"

Begin["`Private`"]

Needs["LP`Sub`"]

dummy[s_] := subformat[s]

End[]

EndPackage[]

For Sub.wl:
(* ::Package:: *)

BeginPackage["LP`Sub`"]

subformat::usage = "subformat[s] format string s, say, to uppercase"

Begin["`Private`"]

subformat[s_]:= ToUpperCase[s]

End[]
EndPackage[]

When I do:  FindFile["LP"]` the function returns with "/Users/twan/LP/Kernel/init.wl" as expected.
However, when I do:  Needs["LP"]` it complains:

I've no clue what has gone wrong, because everything seems to work. Checking the  $ContextPath gives: "LPMain, ..." as desired, moreover, dummy works as expected.
dummy["test"]
TEST

My questions are:

What and why does Mathematica complains with the message?
Except from Off[Needs::nocont], what do I do to prevent this?

This is a very simplified version of my big project and it behaves a bit different but with a similar annoyance: the same message occurs when Main.wl loads Sub.wl.
Thanks for reading this far anyway.

Is there a particular reason why you are not including Get["LP\Sub`"]insideinit.m` ?

I'm looking for a way to isolate the symbols created in LPSub and used in LPMain from the LP package user. And free myself from including them in LPMain to keep the code size manageable. Just a bit of (source code) modularisation.

You will get many more answers by asking at https://mathematica.stackexchange.com . Anyway. I think that you should load the additional LP\Sub`by using the second argument toBeginPackage`

@gdelfino, yes, that is a good idea indeed. kuba already suggested that earlier somewhere else and post the very same question there too.
